# VSCode: /usr/bin/node: bad option: --inspect since last upgrade?

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I'm on **Kubuntu** running most recent stable build of VSCode to develop GO programs. Since last update (VSCode version 1.39.0), my build task is no longer working. All I get is these two lines in Debug Console:

> /usr/bin/node --inspect=17112 --debug-brk
>   /usr/bin/node: bad option: --inspect=17112

I sadly have no clue how come? I did not change the project or any source recently. I also can not find any *--inspect* option in any of my code.

I first run my makefile and then I execute the resulting executable. This worked great since a few months and now it stopped working.

This is my **launch.json**:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type":"node2",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Build and Launch my program",
      "program": "",
      "args": [],
      "preLaunchTask": "make",
      "postDebugTask": "execute",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my **tasks.json**:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "make",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "make",
      "args": [],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "execute",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${workspaceFolder}/myExecutable",
      "args": [
        "-c",
        "/tmp/myTemp",
        "-i",
        "-v",
        "-l",
        "box.log"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I already tried replacing *node2* with *node* and *protocol*, but it behaves exactly the same. Seems it does not matter?

Comment: BTW, it behaves the same with VSCode 1.39.1 :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally replaced "node" or "node2" debugger by the "go" debugger. There is a "mode":"exec" option allowing me to simply executa the program compiled before by the makefile.

This is my working configuration:

**launch.json**

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type":"go",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Build and Launch my executable",
      "mode":"exec",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/myExecutable",
      "args": [
        "-c",
        "/tmp/regibox",
        "-i",
        "-v",
        "-l",
        "box.log"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "make",
      "postDebugTask": "",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my **tasks.json**:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "make",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "make",
      "args": [],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With this, I can simply execute the makefile and run the resulting executable with F5. Of course, no debugging this way :-(